# Python script import from PATH in C++

Tags: c++, python, import, path

I'm trying to run a Python script in a C++ program using `Python.h`. Because this C++ program can be installed (`make install`) in `/usr/bin`, it needs to be able to find the Python script both in its own directory (in case it was not installed) or in one of the PATH environment variable's directories.

I have tried doing :

```
PyObject *pName = PyString_FromString(scriptName); // scriptName is "file.py" as a char*
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\".\")");
PyObject *pModule = PyImport_Import(name); // not working because absolute path only
                                           //since Python 2.7 ?
```

and

```
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\".\")");
PyObject *pModule = PyImport_ImportModuleEx(scriptName, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

But both leave me with `pModule == NULL` after this call but work if I run the C++ module from its own directory.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Few questions:
1) Will the application be run from the directory containing the python script?
2) Have you tried calling PySys_SetArgvEx before Py_Initialize, and setting the application path?

Comment: 1) Absolutely, `make` puts the C++ executable in the same directory where the Python script is located. `make install` copies both the C++ executable and the Python script in `usr/bin` (or wherever the user wants to install those). 2) I have not, mostly because this part of the C++ program is pretty far away from the `main` and thus of the original `argc` and `argv` variables. Do I need to do that to set the application path ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"."` works as a path to your python scripts only if your C++ python script's root directory
is the **current working directory** of your process.

If your program was started from somewhere else (either via PATH or by /path/to/a/program)
then the only reliable way to find your scripts is to use use your `argv[0]` param from `main`.

Once you find the correct path, there are two ways to use it:

1. pass it to `sys.path.append`
2. switch the **working directory** there using `chdir` (from unistd.h), and then you can pass `"."` to `sys.path.append`. The `chdir` will affect the whole process, but pros is that you can do it directly in `main`.

Comment: That's what I fear, from what I read, studying argv[0] is not a fully reliable thing to do... Thanks for the clear answer however !